# Typescript generic Promise return T or void

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in typescript to define a Promise to be a generic or a void?

```
new Promise<T | void>((resolve: () => void, reject: () => void) => {}
```

Above is what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: I think the lack of answers reflect the lack of information in your question. Provide a bit of context w.r.t. the problem you're trying to solve pls.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options for you:

For reference, this gives an error:

```
new Promise<Date>((resolve, reject) => { }).then((x: Date) => x);
new Promise<Date>((resolve, reject) => { }).then((x: void) => x); // error
```

Simply using the type `T | void` inline resolves the error.

```
new Promise<Date | void>((resolve, reject) => { }).then((x: Date) => x);
new Promise<Date | void>((resolve, reject) => { }).then((x: void) => x);
```

Another approach is to create a generic `PromiseOrVoid<T>` class like this:

```
class PromiseOrVoid<T> extends Promise<T | void> { }

new PromiseOrVoid<Date>((resolve, reject) => { }).then((x: Date) => x);
new PromiseOrVoid<Date>((resolve, reject) => { }).then((x: void) => x);
```

Here are [all three in a TypeScript fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=new%20Promise%3CDate%3E((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D).then((x%3A%20Date)%20%3D%3E%20x)%3B%0D%0Anew%20Promise%3CDate%3E((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D).then((x%3A%20void)%20%3D%3E%20x)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Promise%3CDate%20%7C%20void%3E((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D).then((x%3A%20Date)%20%3D%3E%20x)%3B%0D%0Anew%20Promise%3CDate%20%7C%20void%3E((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D).then((x%3A%20void)%20%3D%3E%20x)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20PromiseOrVoid%3CT%3E%20extends%20Promise%3CT%20%7C%20void%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20PromiseOrVoid%3CDate%3E((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D).then((x%3A%20Date)%20%3D%3E%20x)%3B%0D%0Anew%20PromiseOrVoid%3CDate%3E((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D).then((x%3A%20void)%20%3D%3E%20x)%3B).